# Palabra "pesetero" de uso más general

Tags: vocabulario, solicitud-de-término

En España se usa la palabra **[pesetero](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Sn5W8W3)** para referirse a alguien que tiene un marcado o excesivo interés por el dinero, haciendo clara referencia a las pasadas **pesetas** (antes de la introducción del Euro).

¿Hay alguna palabra que pueda aplicarse de manera más general, es decir, en los países en que se usa otra moneda?

Como aún no encuentro una, había pensado en utilizar la misma derivación con las monedas de algunos países, pero no es una buena solución:

- Dolarero
- Pesero ?
- Bolivariano ?
- Colonero ?
- Quetzalero
- Solero ?
- etc.

Habría algunas que tampoco se entenderían en otros países, y otras que serían ambiguas...

Por otra parte, palabras como **interesado** o **ambicioso** tampoco son una buena solución porque los intereses y las ambiciones pueden ser de diversos tipos o en diversas cosas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No veo que haya una palabra tan acertada para connotar negativamente *la propensión o el interés exclusivo de alguien por el dinero* como lo hace **pesetero**.

En la lista de substituciones posibles anoto:

> ***codicioso*** (o ávido)
>   [adjetivo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9dB3fDG) aplicable al que tiene un "afán excesivo de riqueza"

(Por encima de *tacaño* o *avaro*, ambos con con un cariz centrado en la posesión de una riqueza —por la vía de una restricción en el gasto— e indirectamente denotando algo de la  obsesión **por la ganancia de ésta**).

Una alternativa, más genérica acaso, es:

> [***ventajista***](https://servicios.elpais.com/diccionarios/castellano/ventajista)
>   (adj.) Que actúa sin escrúpulos o aprovecha cualquier circunstancia para obtener ventaja o sacar provecho.

Otra, que pensé recién, y cabe es

> [***materialista***](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ObXlVnS)
>
> adj. Dicho de una persona: Excesivamente preocupada por los bienes materiales.

Algo que escuché —y la RAE consigna poseer una acepción peyorativa es

> ***[fenicio](https://dle.rae.es/?id=HksquK1)***
>
> adj. coloq. Que tiene habilidad para comerciar o negociar y sacar el máximo beneficio. U. t. en sent. despect. U. t. c. s.

También

> ***[usurero](https://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=usurero)***
>
> 3. m. y f. Persona que en algunos contratos o negocios obtiene lucro desmedido.

Por último, sólo como dato curioso, agrego un calificativo regional,—cual sobrenombre usado en el exacto sentido de "pesetero"—,  y que escuché decir a mi abuela sobre alguien,

> ***pilla-moneda***

La referencia es del Noroeste Argentino, y por lo tanto solo la encuentro  en publicaciones de Santiago del Estero y Tucumán. En en [*Los sobrenombres santiagueños*](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=VxsJAQAAIAAJ&q=%22pilla-moneda%22&dq=%22pilla-moneda%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6kNnszP7kAhXPE7kGHZrTDRkQ6AEIKTAA)

[image: captura término en sobrenombres santiagueños] y [la siguiente captura](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caO9y.png) en [*La torre de los ingleses (crónicas de viaje*)](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=XmQzAQAAIAAJ&q=pilla-moneda&dq=pilla-moneda&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR8_vUzP7kAhVbFbkGHaWVBXEQ6AEINTAC)

[image: pilla-moneda]

Comment: ¿Si?   No quise aludir a algo diferente; usé _"propensión (inclinación) o interés exclusivo"_ para referir al *dar mucha importancia* al dinero. puedo equivocarme, pero francamente no veo la distancia significativa entre ambas alusiones

Comment: Gracias @user2325442 por tu respuesta, de momento la que más me convence, y creo que sea ajusta mejor, es **materialista**, en la cual no había pensado tampoco.

Comment: @Andrés Chandía, ¿hay algún uso especial que quieras darle al término?¿o la piensas para un contexto. específico?. Tengo la sensación de que hay más posibilidades, —informales—, por ahí guardadas (se me ocurren palabras en ese sentido quizás aplicables a actitudes de alguien así  *mercantilizado* o calificativos de aire amonestante,  como *mercenario*, *usurero*, etc)

Answer (score 2):

No se que tan amplio sea el uso pero en mi entorno se usa **metalizado**

Es genérica ya que no se refiere a ninguna moneda en particular sino al simple metal.

Una corta búsqueda me llevó a [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/definicion/metalizado) donde se define asi:

> Volverse una persona excesivamente interesada por el dinero:

De igual forma la RAE define [metalizado](https://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=metalizado) como :

> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que sobrepone el dinero a cualquier otro bien. U. t. c. s.

La RAE no le da una etiqueta de región por lo que se supondría de uso general, que es propiamente lo que preguntas.

Comment: Gracias @DGaleano, algo así estaba buscando, ahora sólo habría que darle más uso para convertirla en generalizada y ampliamente entendida...